# Can I generate variables inside a mixin to use it outside, without !global?

Tags: sass

I'm creating a theme system and want to reuse some vars depending on the scope, like:

```
.black-friday {
    @include generate-theme('black', 'yellow');
}

.light-theme {
    @include generate-theme('blue', 'pink');
}

.dark-theme {
    @include generate-theme('black', 'orange');
}
```

I don't want to declare a variable with `!global` since it would overwrite the previous var, and would not exist in a closed scope.

I want to use it in a scope, so that I can change the theme easily with only one class changing.

This was my attempt:

```
$colors: (
    pink: (
        light: lighten(#F91364, 20),
        normal: #F91364,
        dark: darken(#F91364, 20)
    ),
    blue: (
        light: lighten(#3E61FF, 20),
        normal: #3E61FF,
        dark: darken(#3E61FF, 20)
    ),
);

$contrasts: (
    pink: (
        light: #eee,
        normal: #fff,
        dark: #fff
    ),
    blue: (
        light: #eee,
        normal: #fff,
        dark: #fff
    )
)

@function get-color($color, $force: 'normal') {
    $chosenColor: map-get($colors, $color);
    @return map-get($chosenColor, $force);
}

@function get-contrast($color, $force: 'normal') {
    $chosenColor: map-get($contrasts, $color);
    @return map-get($chosenColor, $force);
}

@mixin generate-theme($primary, $accent) {
    $primary-color: get-color($primary);
    $primary-light-color: get-color($primary, 'light');
    $primary-dark-color: get-color($primary, 'dark');

    $primary-contrast-color: get-contrast($primary);
    $primary-light-contrast-color: get-contrast($primary, 'light');
    $primary-dark-contrast-color: get-contrast($primary, 'dark');

    $accent-color: get-color($accent);
    $accent-light-color: get-color($accent, 'light');
    $accent-dark-color: get-color($accent, 'dark');

    $accent-contrast-color: get-contrast($accent);
    $accent-light-contrast-color: get-contrast($accent, 'light');
    $accent-dark-contrast-color: get-contrast($accent, 'dark');
}
```

Comment: Which variables should not be global? The colors?

Comment: The ones generate through the `@mixin generate-theme`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am getting all that right, than the answer is: No, not possible, those variables are local and the only way to make them global is, well, to use `!global`, to make them global. I another Option:

A `@function get-variables($primary, $accent)` which returns a map containing all the variables as key, value pairs, which can be called where ever needed.

Or you need to change your code in a way that `@mixin generate-theme` itself includes all other mixins with appropriate parameters.

Comment: I did the `@function` approach before moving to creating classes/selectors and extendind them. That way I can create the theme system I was wishing for. Thanks o/